# Angular 6 HTTP 409 Conflict when requesting a url with httpclient with authorization header

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm deveoping an Angular 6 application that will request some data from a  remote api.I'm using HttpClient to obtain access_token.

However when I do a post request using the authorization header that contains the access_token,I receive HTTP 409 CONFLICT:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict) [...SOME URL...]

Here is part of the api.service.ts file which is the service class of the application:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}
  apiURL:string="SOME URL";
  tokenURL:string="SOME URL";

  getSurveys(){
    var tokenData={
      "username": "...",
      "password": "...",
      "client_type": 1
      }

      this.http.post(this.tokenURL,tokenData).subscribe((res)=>{    
        var access_token=res["access_token"];
        var header = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders()
            .append('Content-Type','application/json')
            .append('Authorization', `bearer ${access_token}`)
        }

        var requestData={
          "skip":1,
          "take":2,
          "search":""
        }

        this.http.post(this.apiURL,requestData,header).subscribe((res)=> 
        {
            alert(res);
        });

      });       
  }
}
```

I can receive the access_token from the first request.I expect to receive the response from the second Http post request and that the application alerts the response message.

Comment: I believe the error is not in your angular application, but in the server, is there more information in the response ?

Comment: We can't tell you why your server sends such a response. You need to look that up in the body of the response you get, or in the documentation or the source code of your server API. Usually, the header value starts by `Bearer`, not `bearer`. That might be an explanation.